# How to run TestNG multiple TestClass using ANT?

Tags: testng

I am testing my web project using TestNG. In my project, I have 3 test classes with set of @Test methods, say

- ClassA
- ClassB
- ClassC

I want to execute all these Test class (they are my TestCases) in sequence. How should i write my testng.xml and build.xml to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u wanna make this Class A, B, C running in a sequence ..

I would suggest u create a ClassD(), then u control the calling sequence of ClassA.method(), ClassB.method(), ClassC.method() inside the ClassD().

@Test shall reside in your ClassD

Your Build.XML shall be configure to

```
<suite name="xxx" parallel="none">
  <test name="xxx" preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
       <class name="package.ClassD"/>
    </classes>
  </test>   
</suite>
```

Comment: I agree this is one of the solution. But i want to understand can`t this be achieve through build.xml file. Can i control order from build.xml file ?

Comment: hi @Amitbaderia u may refer to this http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html (Section 5.7 Dependencies) this mightbe something that u r looking for :D

Comment: yes it can be controlled with the testng.xml file too. I just don't remember how off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

> //TestNG can use priorities as which order to handle the methods.
>
> import blah; import testng_Annotations;
>
> @BeforeTest
>
> BeforeTestMethod()
>
> @Test (priority=1)
>
> ClassA.method()
>
> @Test (priority=2)
>
> ClassB.method()
>
> @Test(priority=3)
>
> ClassC.method()
>
> @AfterTest
>
> EndTestMethod()

Ensure your testng.xml calls this new java file.